# Selecting Most Highly Variant Features

Tags: r, variance

I'm trying to select the most highly variant features of a matrix, where I have my features per column vs the samples per row.

With the following data frame, how can I determine the variance and from here extract the top 3 features with high variance for example my dataframe. Do I just need to account for the variance or also consider the coefficient of variance?

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=4),
                  var2 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=3),
                  var3 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=2),
                  var4 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=8),
                  var5 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=6))
```

Would something like:

```
HighVarianceFeatures <- apply(dat, 2, var)

dat[HighVarianceFeatures,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach where you first calculate the variance of all columns, then use the results to find the column names that you want to select.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(22)

dat <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=4),
                  var2 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=3),
                  var3 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=2),
                  var4 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=8),
                  var5 = rnorm(n=20, mean = 1, sd=6))

# Create summary of variances
var_df = dat %>% 
  summarise(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = var)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  slice_max(n = 3, order_by = value)

var_df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 var4   60.2
#> 2 var5   26.4
#> 3 var1   17.4

# Get the columns with most variance from the data
dat %>% 
  select(var_df$name)
#>           var4       var5       var1
#> 1  -5.33673229  7.5552788 -1.0485564
#> 2  12.37326940  3.1473576 10.9407347
#> 3  -0.23404055 -2.7882345  5.0313046
#> 4  -0.05347699  4.9220310  2.1712583
#> 5  -6.07849538 11.0700901  0.1641626
#> 6  14.70761000 -8.1716054  8.4323696
#> 7   2.27490161  4.5540096  0.7358944
#> 8  17.84011187 -6.4405093  0.3489402
#> 9  -1.35200889 -6.6220732  0.2005573
#> 10 -4.27056119 -6.3205654  2.2022469
#> 11 -2.99082873  4.7375756 -2.0556291
#> 12 -0.61282537  0.9324339  1.3278476
#> 13 -2.46047250  3.6783841  3.9721131
#> 14 -2.14505115 -0.2360501  0.6639112
#> 15  3.77258671  3.4759149 -2.1715781
#> 16 -2.89472639  0.5849991 -2.6886145
#> 17 -5.58112437 -0.9994997  4.4462495
#> 18  2.75624898 -1.3876128  9.0117688
#> 19 17.97297820 -2.0069021  4.7462041
#> 20  8.18860550 -3.6364293 -5.4629395
```

Alternatively, here is a solution in base R

````r
dat[, apply(dat, 2, var) >= max(tail(sort(apply(dat, 2, var), decreasing = TRUE), n = 3))]

#>           var4       var5       var1
#> 1  -5.33673229  7.5552788 -1.0485564
#> 2  12.37326940  3.1473576 10.9407347
#> 3  -0.23404055 -2.7882345  5.0313046
#> 4  -0.05347699  4.9220310  2.1712583
#> 5  -6.07849538 11.0700901  0.1641626
#> 6  14.70761000 -8.1716054  8.4323696
#> 7   2.27490161  4.5540096  0.7358944
#> 8  17.84011187 -6.4405093  0.3489402
#> 9  -1.35200889 -6.6220732  0.2005573
#> 10 -4.27056119 -6.3205654  2.2022469
#> 11 -2.99082873  4.7375756 -2.0556291
#> 12 -0.61282537  0.9324339  1.3278476
#> 13 -2.46047250  3.6783841  3.9721131
#> 14 -2.14505115 -0.2360501  0.6639112
#> 15  3.77258671  3.4759149 -2.1715781
#> 16 -2.89472639  0.5849991 -2.6886145
#> 17 -5.58112437 -0.9994997  4.4462495
#> 18  2.75624898 -1.3876128  9.0117688
#> 19 17.97297820 -2.0069021  4.7462041
#> 20  8.18860550 -3.6364293 -5.4629395
```
````

Comment: Oh wow thanks @mhvod, this is really cool :) was just wondering if using the original method of just calculating the variance for each column with apply is not enough. and take the variance from there. Thanks for this :)

Comment: You could also use apply, I have added a base R approach to my answer.

Comment: thanks again :D